# unexpectedly found nil unexpectedly - struct init? not working

Tags: swift, struct, option-type

I am working on a demo app to return a list of restaurant with the google places API.

- I have a `Restaurant` class - 1 property is a custom type `RestaurantDetails`. This is where the challenge is:

**Restaurant.swift**

```
class Restaurant {

    var id:String
    var placeId:String
    var name:String
    var location: Location //Location + address + coordinate + distance
    var phone:String?
    let details : RestaurantDetails


    init(id:String, placeId:String, name:String, location: Location, details: RestaurantDetails) {
        self.id = id
        self.placeId = placeId
        self.name = name
        self.location = location
        self.details = details
    }

    convenience init(dict:[String:Any]) {
        let id = dict["id"] as! String
        let placeId = dict["place_id"] as! String
        let name = dict["name"] as! String
        let address = dict["formatted_address"] as? String
        let location = Location(address: address!, json: dict["geometry"] as! [String : Any])

        if let price = dict["price_level"] as? Double {
            print("price => \(Price(valueDouble: price))")
        }

        if let rating = dict["rating"] as? Double {
            print("rating => \(Rating(valueDouble: rating))")
        }

        self.init(id: id, placeId: placeId, name: name, location: location!, details: RestaurantDetails(json: dict)!)
    }

}
```

[image: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional]
the initialization of the details property fails each time
even using the breakpoint does not help to debug the error because the custom init? does not seem to fire. I do not see any syntax error though
I am usually using guard let control flow to parse the JSON format if the value exists. unsuccessful.
the breakpoint does not kick in on the `RestaurantDetails.swift` file

**RestaurantDetails.swift**

```
enum Price {
    case cheap, expensive, `default`

    init(valueDouble: Double) {
        switch valueDouble {
        case 0..<2: self = .cheap
        case 2..<4 : self = .expensive
        default: self = .default
        }
    }

    var dollarSymbol : String {
        switch self {
        case .cheap: return "$"
        case .expensive: return "$$"
        default: return ""
        }
    }
}

enum Rating {
    case low, fair, good, excellent, `default`

    init(valueDouble: Double) {
        switch valueDouble {
        case 0..<2: self = .low
        case 3..<4: self = .fair
        case 4..<5: self = .good
        case 6 : self = .excellent
        default: self = .default
        }
    }

    var starSymbol : String {
        switch self {
        case .low: return "⭐"
        case .fair: return "⭐⭐"
        case .good: return "⭐⭐⭐"
        case .excellent: return "⭐⭐⭐⭐"
        default: return ""
        }
    }
}

struct RestaurantDetails {
    let price:Price
    let rating:Rating // Rating (enum) (filter)
    let openNow: Bool //(filter)
    let types : [String]?
    let photos : [NSDictionary]?
}


extension RestaurantDetails {

    init?(json: [String: Any]) {

        guard let price = json["price_level"] as? Double,
            let rating = json["rating"] as? Double,
            let openingHours = json["opening_hours"] as? NSDictionary,
            let types = json["types"] as? [String],
            let photos = json["photos"] as? [NSDictionary] else {
            return nil
        }

        print("json details : \(json)")

        self.price = Price(valueDouble: price)
        self.rating = Rating(valueDouble: rating)
        self.openNow = openingHours["open_now"] as! Bool != nil ?? false
        self.types = types
        self.photos = photos
    }
}
```

I also have a `Location.swift` file that works perfectly

```
struct Location {
    var address :String
    var coordinate:(lat:Double, lng:Double)
}

extension Location {
    init?(address: String, json:[String:Any]) {
        guard let latitude = json["location"] as? NSDictionary, let longitude = json["location"] as? NSDictionary else { return nil }

        self.init(address: address, coordinate: (lat: latitude["lat"] as! Double, lng: longitude["lng"] as! Double))
    }
}
```

Comment: Any carelessly written exclamation mark can cause a crash. Handle optionals safely. That's very basic stuff in Swift. You are declaring `Location` with a failable initializer but you don't handle the case the `init` method returns `nil`.

Comment: my first though was that you forcibly unwrap every possible optionals you have... I just wondered why not crashed your app at an earlier stage.

Comment: With that many forcibly unwrapped optionals, I would be surprised if there *wasn't* a crash.

Comment: it crashes yes I confirm. I would appreciate more pointers, because the init?does not fire in the RestaurantDetails. finding an nil object is pretty easy. it is shown in the debugger.

Comment: I have tested different approach. the guard let will always return a nil object if only one object is nil (or with 1 json parsing error). What is the best approach to handle parsing json for several values when not all key/value are guaranteed to exist.

Comment: guard let price = json["price_level"] as? Double,
            let rating = json["rating"] as? Double,
            let openingHours = json["opening_hours"] as? NSDictionary,
            let types = json["types"] as? [String],
            let photos = json["photos"] as? [NSDictionary] else {
            return nil
        }
does not seem to be a good solution

Comment: print and see what's in your location and address variables one of them is nil @SandyL

Comment: I am asking how to handle control flow for many json parsed. I know that one is nil if the init fails

Answer (score 1):

[As vadian described in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47711996/unexpectedly-found-nil-unexpectedly-struct-init-not-working#comment82383944_47711996), the issue causing the crash is that `location` has a failable initializer, you are forcibly unwrapping it, and since initialization is in fact failing, you have now force-unwrapped a nil value.

The broader questions are: what do you, the developer, want to happen when some or all location data is not available, and what is the best way to go about doing that?

### Options for handling incomplete or missing location data

Based on your description of the problem (“a demo app to return a list of restaurant with the google places api”), it is not clear whether or not restaurants without useable location data should enter your model. It is also not clear whether or not there is some location data you could do without. So I see three options:

1. Discard all restaurants with incomplete location data
2. Discard some restaurants with incomplete location data while keeping others
3. Keep all restaurants regardless of location data

To implement these options, you may want to use some common tools for dealing with optionals:

#### Nil-coalescing operator

`a = b ?? c`

Set `a` equal to `b`, unless `b` is nil, in which case set `a` equal to `c`.

#### Optional binding in `guard` and `if`

`guard let a = b else { return }`

Set `a` equal to `b` unless `b` is nil, in which case return from the current context. You can do work in the else branch prior to returning.

`if let a = b { /* Do work using a */ } else { /* Do other work */ }`

If `b` is not nil, enter the `if` branch and  set `a` equal to `b`; if `b` is nil, enter the `else` branch.

### How to do it

#### Discard all restaurants with incomplete location data

In this case, you could make a failable initializer for `Restaurant`, guarded by `location` being non-nil:

```
/// Initialization fails if `location` is `nil`
convenience init?(id:String, placeId:String, name:String, location: Location?, details: RestaurantDetails) {
    guard let location = location else { return nil }

    self.init(id: id, placeId: placeId, name: name, location: location, details: details)
}
```

#### Discard some restaurants with incomplete location data while keeping others

You may be able to recover from some kinds of missing location data. For example, it may be the case that you really just need the street address string and the latitude and longitude are inessential. You could rewrite your `Location` struct to reflect that:

```
struct Location {
    var address: String
    var coordinate: (lat: Double, lng: Double)?
}

extension Location {
    init?(address: String, json:[String:Any]) {
        let coordinate: (Double, Double)?
        if let latitude = json["location"] as? NSDictionary, let longitude = json["location"] as? NSDictionary {
            coordinate = (latitude, longitude)
        } else {
            coordinate = nil
        }

        self.init(address: address, coordinate: coordinate)
    }
}
```

Alternative, lat/long might be the important part, but it might sometimes be possible to recover them from the street address using another API:

```
struct Location {
    var address: String
    var coordinate: (lat: Double, lng: Double)
}

extension Location {
    init?(address: String, json:[String:Any]) {
        let coordinate: (Double, Double)?
        if let latitude = json["location"] as? NSDictionary, let longitude = json["location"] as? NSDictionary {
            coordinate = (latitude, longitude)
        } else {

            /* An API call that takes an address string and tries to return lat/long but might return nil */

            coordinate = returnedCoordinateFromAPI
        }

        guard let coordinate = coordinate else { return nil }
        self.init(address: address, coordinate: coordinate)
    }
}
```

#### Keep all restaurants regardless of location data

This is the easiest case. If `location` is not essential, make it optional:

```
class Restaurant {

    var id: String
    var placeId: String
    var name: String
    var location: Location? //Location + address + coordinate + distance
    var phone: String?
    let details: RestaurantDetails


    init(id:String, placeId:String, name:String, location: Location?, details: RestaurantDetails) {

        self.id = id
        self.placeId = placeId
        self.name = name
        self.location = location
        self.details = details
    }

    convenience init?(dict:[String:Any]) {
        guard let id = dict["id"] as? String,
            let placeId = dict["place_id"] as? String,
            let name = dict["name"] as? String else { return nil }

        // Use the address from the dictionary unless it is nil, in which case substitute an empty string
        let address = dict["formatted_address"] as? String ?? ""

        let location = Location(address: address, json: dict["geometry"] as? [String : Any])

        if let price = dict["price_level"] as? Double {
            print("price => \(Price(valueDouble: price))")
        }

        if let rating = dict["rating"] as? Double {
            print("rating => \(Rating(valueDouble: rating))")
        }

        guard let details = RestaurantDetails(json: dict) else { return nil }

        self.init(id: id, placeId: placeId, name: name, location: location, details: details)
    }

}
```